# Delete a namedtuple object from a class defined list

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Below is a class of a deck of cards from 'Fluent Python' by Luciano Romalho.
I hope it's ok that I have copied the code, I really don't have a better more concise class example than this one.

```
import collections
from random import choice

Card = collections.namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])


class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits 
                       for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
    return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        return self._cards[position]
```

so, an instance of this class will have 52 cards, each a namedtuple as defined in 'Card' object.

I wanted to draw a hand of n cards so that it will reflect in the deck.

I tried the following:

```
def a_hand(deck, size):
    the_hand = []
    for n in range(size):
        c = choice(deck)
        the_hand.append(c)
        deck = [i for i in deck if i != c]
    return the_hand
```

so when I try:

```
>> deck = FrenchDeck()
>> a = a_hand(deck, 5)
```

I get a hand but the deck is untouched:

```
>> hand
[Card(rank='9', suit='spades'),
 Card(rank='A', suit='hearts'),
 Card(rank='2', suit='diamonds'),
 Card(rank='8', suit='clubs'),
 Card(rank='10', suit='hearts')]

>> len(deck)
52
```

when I try directly in the interperter:

```
>> c = choice(deck)
>> alt = [i for i in deck if i != c]
```

it works:

```
>> len(alt)
51
```

I understand that this is due to the FrenchDeck's instance not being affected by what is happening in the scope of the function a_hand.

What would be the way to do it? I tried to define a  dunder-delitem  function in the class but didn't get it right, also wasn't sure if this was the right function to use and whether it was to be defined in the Card object or in the FrenchDeck object.

Comment: When you get an item from the deck maybe you should delete it from `self._cards`.

Comment: Your function `a_hand` replaces its parameter `deck` with a new list each time round `size`.

Comment: You could shuffle the deck once with `random.shuffle`  and then `.pop()` from the deck each time you need a card.

Comment: @Wombatz I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Wombatz, the list of namedtuples is immutale and therfor cannot be shuffled. I better change the code to allow that . thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really you just need to move `a_hand` to be a method of `FrenchDeck`:

```
class FrenchDeck:
    # All previous code here, plus:

    def a_hand(self, size):
        the_hand = []
        for n in range(size):
            c = choice(self._cards)
            the_hand.append(c)
            self._cards.remove(c)
        return the_hand
```

Comment: That is the answer I was looking for. Thanks. I just didn't manage to include the remove() method any other way I tried.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that it's due to the fact that `FrenchDeck` instance is not modified inside `a_hand` function. Instead, you only override `deck` variable. To achieve your goal, you could e.g. add `deal_hand` method to `FrenchDeck` class, that will return a hand of given size and remove selected cards from deck itself.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new deck instead of updating the existing deck.

```
deck = [i for i in deck if i != c]
```

This creates a *new* list, built by the list comprehension, and makes `deck` point to it, instead of pointing at the original list that was passed.

You need is to use `deck.remove(...)` if you are to alter the existing list.

(Also: try making the deck and hands sets, not lists. It matches the domain better.)

Comment: thanks. I was trying to use remove() but I kept getting it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you get a card from the deck, also remove it from the deck. Use `list.pop` in `__getitem__`.

```
class FrenchDeck:
    ranks = [str(n) for n in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
    suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

    def __init__(self):
        self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for suit in self.suits 
                       for rank in self.ranks]

    def __len__(self):
        print(f'__len__ called: {len(self._cards)}') 
        return len(self._cards)

    def __getitem__(self, position):
        print(f'getting item {position}')
        return self._cards.pop(position)

def a_hand(deck, size):
    the_hand = []
    for n in range(size):
        print('getting another card')
        c = choice(deck)
        the_hand.append(c)
    return the_hand

deck = FrenchDeck()
a = a_hand(deck, 5)
```

Comment: That looks neat. I will give it a try.